# Rhino Mocks -- assert no interaction with mock/stub

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks, assertion, arrange-act-assert

Is it possible to tell that a mock/stub has seen no interaction at all in RhinoMocks.
Something along the lines of:

```
logger.AssertNoInteraction();
```

Which would assert no method has been called on the stubbed logger.

This would be a much less tedious than calling the following each time:

```
logger.AssertWasNotCalled(l => l.Debug(Arg<string>.Is.Anything()));
logger.AssertWasNotCalled(l => l.Info(Arg<string>.Is.Anything()));
logger.AssertWasNotCalled(l => l.Warning(Arg<string>.Is.Anything()));
logger.AssertWasNotCalled(l => l.Error(Arg<string>.Is.Anything()));
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use a strict mock and you do not set up an expectation you will get an exception if  a call was made to the mock.